# Pruning Decision Trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Below is a snippet of the decision tree as it is pretty huge.

[image]

How to make the tree stop growing when the lowest **value** in a node is under 5. Here is the code to produce the decision tree. On [SciKit - Decission Tree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) we can see the only way to do so is by **min_impurity_decrease** but I am not sure how it specifically works.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


y_train = df['Class']
X_train = df.drop('Class',axis = 1)

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier( random_state=42)                
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

from IPython.display import display, Image
import pydotplus
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import _tree
from sklearn import tree
import collections
import drawtree
import os  

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\graphviz'

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(dt, out_file = 'thisIsTheImagetree.dot',
                                 feature_names=X_train.columns, filled   = True
                                    , rounded  = True
                                    , special_characters = True)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_file('thisIsTheImagetree.dot')  

thisIsTheImage = Image(graph.create_png())
display(thisIsTheImage)
#print(dt.tree_.feature)

from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['dot','-Tpng','thisIsTheImagetree.dot','-o','thisIsTheImagetree.png'])
```

## Update

I think `min_impurity_decrease` can in a way help reach the goal. As tweaking `min_impurity_decrease` does actually prune the tree. Can anyone kindly explain min_impurity_decrease.

I am trying to understand the equation in scikit learn but I am not sure what is the value of right_impurity and left_impurity.

```
N = 256
N_t = 256
impurity = ??
N_t_R = 242
N_t_L = 14
right_impurity = ??
left_impurity = ??

New_Value = N_t / N * (impurity - ((N_t_R / N_t) * right_impurity)
                    - ((N_t_L / N_t) * left_impurity))
New_Value
```

### Update 2

Instead of pruning at a certain value, we prune under a certain condition.
such as
We do split at 6/4 and 5/5 but not at 6000/4 or 5000/5. Let's say if one value is under a certain percentage in comparison with its adjacent value in the node, rather than a certain value.

```
      11/9
   /       \
  6/4       5/5
 /   \     /   \
6/0  0/4  2/2  3/3
```

Comment: What does the value represent? **min_impurity_decrease** is applicable to the split that can happen in a certain node, and does not consider a value of the current node but the increase in purity in the children if one would split the node.

Comment: @SBylemans the **value** term is in the actual decision tree under the term samples

Comment: The left and right impurity are the impurities of the samples in the left child and right child, respectively. (calculated by the **criterion** argument)

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do it with the decission tree from SciKit, unless you maybe know the max-depth or number of samples when the value of under 5 will occur. Maybe it is possible to traverse the tree after construction? The tree is located in `tree_` of the classifier object

Comment: You need to specify which criterion you are using: either gini or entropy. You cannot implement your own function.

Comment: Not according to the documentation: "Criterion : string, optional (default=”gini”) => The function to measure the quality of a split. Supported criteria are “gini” for the Gini impurity and “entropy” for the information gain."

Comment: Is this not just `min_samples_split`?

Comment: @KenSyme min_samples split is for the total samples in the node. The question is, the lowest value in the node. for example [400, 1] you want it to stop splitting. Using **min_samples_split**, it will still split

Comment: Have a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8399), looks like a similar problem trying to solve.

Comment: @KenSyme you are absolutely right ! That is exactly my question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Directly restricting the lowest value (number of occurences of a particular class) of a leaf cannot be done with min_impurity_decrease or any other built-in stopping criteria.

I think the only way you can accomplish this without changing the source code of scikit-learn is to **post-prune** your tree. To accomplish this, you can just traverse the tree and remove all children of the nodes with minimum class count less that 5 (or any other condition you can think of). I will continue your example:

```
from sklearn.tree._tree import TREE_LEAF

def prune_index(inner_tree, index, threshold):
    if inner_tree.value[index].min() < threshold:
        # turn node into a leaf by "unlinking" its children
        inner_tree.children_left[index] = TREE_LEAF
        inner_tree.children_right[index] = TREE_LEAF
    # if there are shildren, visit them as well
    if inner_tree.children_left[index] != TREE_LEAF:
        prune_index(inner_tree, inner_tree.children_left[index], threshold)
        prune_index(inner_tree, inner_tree.children_right[index], threshold)

print(sum(dt.tree_.children_left < 0))
# start pruning from the root
prune_index(dt.tree_, 0, 5)
sum(dt.tree_.children_left < 0)
```

this code will print first `74`, and then `91`. It means that the code has created 17 new leaf nodes (by practically removing links to their ancestors). The tree, which has looked before like

[image]

now looks like

[image]

so you can see that is indeed has decreased a lot.

Comment: but this means its only pruned in the diagram and not actually in the calculation? So if I print the decision path of an instance it will correspond to the full tree, rather than the pruned tree right ?

Comment: No, the tree is pruned in the calculation as well. The nodes that were pruned away still exist in memory, but they are never reached when the tree is used for prediction.

Comment: I used this solution to [write my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398390/4629950), exporting to graphviz and prediction works. max_depth obviously does not get updated, is there anything else I should know before I deploy a model pruned this way? Did you run into any problems afterwards?

Comment: @Thomas no, I didn't have problem with such solutions

Comment: @appleyuchi, you are invited to extend my answer to modify any paremeters you wish :)

Comment: I ran the Decision Tree classifier 20 times on a training set, each iteration using a different value for threshold, from 1-20. Surprisingly, the cross validation accuracy decreased monotonically as threshold (i.e. pruning) increased. This is the opposite of what I'd expect with pruning, which is intended to reduce model complexity and therefore overfitting. This indicates to me that something is fundamentally wrong with this algorithm, or that I missed something and am doing something wrong. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Pruning improves validation accuracy if your model is overfitting - in this case, pruning fights overgeneralization. However, if your model is actually underfitting your training data (e.g. if you have lots of observations, few features, and some constrains already imposrd on the model), then pruning makes the model underfit even more.

Comment: However, you should expect the gap between training and validation accuracy to decrease as you prune the tree more and more. If it doesn't happen, then there is indeed some bug.

Comment: If this bug really happens, please post a separate question about it, with reproducible code.

Comment: @DavidDale Can you make a version of this based on the number of samples? Example if a node leaf or branch has less than 5 samples prune it.

Comment: @kaluk you do not have to prune trees to achieve this - just set `min_samples_leaf` to 5 when you train your tree.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit :** This is not correct as @SBylemans and @Viktor point out in the comments. I'm not deleting the answer since someone else may also think this is the solution.

Set `min_samples_leaf` to 5.

`min_samples_leaf` :

> The minimum number of samples required to be at a leaf node:

**Update :** I think it cannot be done with `min_impurity_decrease`. Think of the following scenario :

```
      11/9
   /         \
  6/4       5/5
 /   \     /   \
6/0  0/4  2/2  3/3
```

According to your rule, you do not want to split node `6/4` since 4 is less than 5 but you want to split `5/5` node. However, splitting `6/4` node has 0.48 information gain and splitting `5/5` has 0 information gain.

Comment: He does not say that 5 represents the number of samples in the node

Comment: @Selcuk this is incorrect ! min_damples_leaf, is in the leaf node. The question is, looking at the minimum value in the node, stop splitting if it is under a certain value.

Comment: @Victor, I see. I misunderstood the question but I think what you are looking for cannot be done with `min_impurity_decrease`. Check updated section of the answer for an example.

Comment: nice explanation

Comment: @SelçukGülcan I have slightly updated the question under the update part. Can we change it to be a percentage of the other? For example to split at 6/4 and 5/5 but not at 6000/4 or 5000/5. Lets say, if one value is under a certain percentage, rather than a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, `min_impurity_decrease` doesn't look as if it would allow growth of any of the nodes you have shown in the snippet you provided (the sum of impurities after splitting equals the pre-split impurity, so there is no **impurity decrease**). However, while it won't give you exactly the result you want (terminate node if lowest value is under 5), it may give you something similar.

If my testing is right, the official docs make it look more complicated than it actually is. Just take the lower value from the potential parent node, then subtract the sum of the lower values of the proposed new nodes - this is the **gross** impurity reduction.  Then divide by the total number of samples in the **whole tree** - this gives you the **fractional impurity decrease** achieved if the node is split.

If you have 1000 samples, and a node with a lower value of 5 (i.e. 5 "impurities"), 5/1000 represents the maximum impurity decrease you could achieve if this node was perfectly split.  So setting a `min_impurity_decrease` of of 0.005 would approximate stopping the leaf with <5 impurities.  It would actually stop most leaves with a bit more than 5 impurities (depending upon the impurities resulting from the proposed split), so it is only an approximation, but as best I can tell its the closest you can get without post-pruning.

Answer (score 1):

In Scikit learn library, you have parameter called `ccp_alpha` as parameter for `DescissionTreeClassifier`.  Using this you can do post-compexity-pruning for DecessionTrees.  Check this out https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html

Comment: I would definitely vote this answer up, if you elaborate on the answer or maybe add some examples.

Comment: Believe this would help you out
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLOyyFHbiqo